# Save in MYSQL the value of a div with HTML5 Drag &Drop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, drag-and-drop

it´s very simple, I have 3 little divs (1, 2, 3) and need to put them in another 3 divs (4, 5, 6). No problem, but then I need to save the data on MySQL, like 4-1, 5-2, 6-3 for example...I can put a javascript alert to display the number (id), but...how can I save it with PHP to MySQL? It´s not a form, I can´t send it by Get...ideas to help this noob please? Thanks!

Comment: Make an ajax request to a php script and post the data to save in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with ajax.On button click get the div value and send it to php page for mysyql insertion

```
var value= $('#div1').html();
$.ajax({
url: 'save.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {
value: value
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can get 4-1, 5-2, 6-3 value from your javascript code, then pass the same value to your another php code which is having database connection and query to insert value to table using AJAX technique.

Answer (score 0):

using ajax submit your data to data.php page and then you should use following mysql query to insert values in database

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host-name","username","password","database name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tablename(col1, col2, col3)
VALUES ('value1', 'value2','value3')");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```